# protractor delay between two instances in parallel execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing, protractor

i'm using protractor to automate my application.
I can execute my test cases efficiently both in sequential and parallel.
But while executing in parallel i.e., in 4 instances at a time it is hitting my Application Data Base which results in some DB dead lock issues.

here is my conf.js file

```
capabilities: {

        'browserName': 'chrome',
          shardTestFiles: true,
          maxInstances: 4
    },
```

I wonder is there any way to add delay between instances in parallel execution lets say around 10 to 15 secs delay between instances. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`browser.driver.sleep(15000);` should do the trick at the begining of the test u want to delay

Comment: thank you, but your answer supports for 3 to 4 test cases. But my test suite consists of 600+ specs i cant insert driver.sleep in every spec.